# ubuntu server 22.04.3 LTS - system has been minimized

Tags: server, system-installation

I have done a fresh install with Ubuntu Server 22.04.3 LTS. I'm amazed by this
When I reboot, I have:

```
This system has been minimized by removing packages and content that are
not required on a system that users do not log into.
To restore this content, you can run the 'unminimize' command.
```

and it is waiting for the service to restart that it offers me: why doesn't it start the services it needs automatically?

bus
lxcfs
lxc.monitord
lxc-net
networkd-dispatchher
packagekit
polkit
systemd-login
unexpected-upgrade
user

thank you for the explanations

Comment: does [this reference](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Minimal) help explain?